# group_by() and summarise() error

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I want to make a data frame which has the mean and median of friend_count variable which is from another data frame 'pf' by the function group_by() and summarise().

But when I try this command, the result is like below, showing the mean and median of the whole column of friend_count without grouping by age.

Please help!

```
library(dplyr)

pf.fc_by_age <- pf %>% group_by(age) %>%
              summarise(friend_count_mean = mean(friend_count),
                        friend_count_median = median(friend_count))
pf.fc_by_age
friend_count_mean friend_count_median
  1 196.3508 82
```

Comment: may be you loaded `plyr` as well.  Use `%>% dplyr::summarise(friend_count_mean=`

Comment: So simple!! Thanks a lot:)

Comment: @Jean this is why some advice to use the syntax `package::function()` instead of only `function()`. While you might have other bugs, it would not be because of package conflicts/masking ;)

Answer (score 1):

I just have the same problem. Later on, I realised that the package `plyr` may be conflicted with tidyverse. When I loaded only tidyverse and avoided using `plyr` which solved my problem.

Comment: tidyverse is dependent on `dplyr`. You cannot load tidyverse without dplyr.

Comment: oh, sorry it was `plyr` package to use `rbind.fill()` which caused the problem for summarising mean in my case.